# Error while trying to fetch stored procedure result, but ordinary query works fine

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Im trying to get a resultset into an array.. therefore i did the following attempt which turned out to be successful

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table_count)){
$table = $row["TABLE_NAME"];

foreach ($tables as $table) {
         $excute = mysql_query("
         SELECT  DISTINCT b.ID, name, accountname, c.accountID, status, total_impr, min(a.timestamp), max(a.timestamp)
         FROM    ",table_1," a INNER JOIN bookers b on a.ID = b.ID INNER JOIN accounts c on b.accountID = c.accountID
         WHERE   a.timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR)
         GROUP BY ID;") or die(mysql_error());
         $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($excute);
         var_dump($result);
     }
```

Then to increase the quality of the code i included that query inside a stored proceedure... there afterwards when i call that stored proceedure like below it gives an error saying

```
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

The code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table_count)){
    $table = $row["TABLE_NAME"];

foreach ($tables as $table) {
     $excute = mysql_query("CALL mySP_1('$table')") or die(mysql_error());
     $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($excute);
     var_dump($result);
 }
```

the stored proceedure

```
BEGIN   

SET @sqlstring = CONCAT("
SELECT  DISTINCT b.ID, name, accountname, c.accountID, status, total_impr, min(a.timestamp), max(a.timestamp)
FROM    ",table_1," a INNER JOIN bookers b on a.ID = b.ID INNER JOIN accounts c on b.accountID = c.accountID

WHERE   a.timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR)
GROUP BY ID;");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstring;
    EXECUTE stmt;

END$$
```

**Can anybody spot why does it work fine with a normal query and it returns an error with stored proceedure.. I have been trying to fix this for sometime but nothing worked**

Can anybody help me out on this to work it with the stored procedure

Comment: anymore suggestions guys

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures are not working with the Mysql_* functions.

Beter to switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: can you just give me guide how to use it in this particular instance